# Problem with subnode's text when scraping data from a website with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Hope somebody can help this newbie.

I tried many paths for this subnodes but i cant figure it out.

Html part:

```
 <div class="center-block"> == $0
    <div class="match-time" id="dvStatusText">MS</div>
    <div class="match-score" id="dvScoreText">4 - 0</div>
    <div class="hf-match-score" id="dvHTScoreText">İY : 3- 0</div>
 </div>
```

My code:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Mac/3213138/");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
try
   {
      string html = client.DownloadString(url);
      HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
      doc.LoadHtml(html);
      HtmlNodeCollection results = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='center-block']"); // 
       if (results != null)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
           { 
             var t1 = results[i].SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='match-score']").InnerText; // (FT)
             var t2 = results[i].SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='dvHTScoreText']").InnerText; // ht
             listBox1.Items.Add(t2.ToString());
           }
    }
```

My problem from InnerHtml result:

```
 <div class="match-time" id="dvStatusText">MS</div>
 <div class="match-score" id="dvScoreText">4 - 0</div>
 <div class="hf-match-score" id="dvHTScoreText"></div> // this element has always contains text.
```

I tried different ways to solve this problem but i have nothing. I can scrape "class=match time" or "class=match-score". But i cant "class=hf-match-score" . I have tried scrape with class or id. Different ways same problem.
Please show me a way. Thanks alot.

Comment: What's the output if you change your XPath expression for : `.//*[@id='dvHTScoreText']` (i.e. : `.` at the beginning of the expression to specify you're working from the context node) ?

Comment: I tried and same result. But i realise this, when i download html file, this element (class="hf-match-score") haven't a text . how it possible

Comment: <div class="center-block">
     <div class="match-time" id="dvStatusText">MS</div>
     <div class="match-score" id="dvScoreText">4 - 0</div>
     <div class="hf-match-score" id="dvHTScoreText"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The score at half-time is displayed with Javascript. You'll need Selenium or a similar tool to access this element.

As an alternative, you can fetch the data directly from the JSON loaded in the background.
Piece of code in Python (I suppose you can do the same in c#) :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

# We set up the download url (obtained in the network tab of the developer tool) and the mandatory header

url = 'http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Match/MatchData.aspx?t=dtl&id=3213138&s=0'
hd = {'Referer': 'http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Mac/3213138/'}

# We download and parse the json

data = requests.get(url,headers=hd)
val= data.json()

# We extract values of interest

print(val["d"]["s"],val["d"]["ht"],sep="\n")
```

Output :

```
4 - 0
3 - 0
```

Comment: Thanks alot my hero :) I did it with selenium. I was blind and u open my eyes :)